# How to convert strings to links in Angular and nesting the links into HTML

Tags: html, angular, linkify

So I'm building a basic app using nodejs and Angular, where users can post stuff that may contain links and I'm trying to figure out how can I make the links that they share clickable in the frontend.

I did some reseach and I've found this library called **linkify** that turns string into links but in order to use you will have to use the innerHtml property and i prefer not to because then if a user writes html code as a post it will get nested too.

Is there a solution for me to nest only the link that I want instead of the whole content of the post?

Answer (score 1):

Just use angular property binding

```
 <a [href]="website.url" [textContent]="website.name"> </a>
```

Comment: This doens't solve my problem, this is nesting the whole post, I want to display the content of the post and nest the link only as html tag

Comment: For a better understanding of what you are trying to achieve. Could you please create some sample stackblitz.

Comment: Let's say display my posts this way

`<div  *ngFor="let post of posts">
   <p>{{post.content}}</p>
 </div>`

Basically this post.content may or may not contain a url, in case there's one I want to transform it into a link and nest into the DOM so it can be clickable

Comment: I don't want to use the innerhtml property because in case there's some html code in the post.content it will get nested too

Comment: In that case, I guess there is only one way, you have to use regex that searches the link inside the content of your post and converts that into a hyperlink